# Passing an anonymous attribute to Html.BeginForm in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I add an anonymous attribute in a form's header using Html.BeginForm? For instance, I have:`@using (Html.BeginForm("ProfileSetting", "Profile", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @string = "editable-form", @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", name = "myform", onaftersave = "saveSettings()" }))`

I would like the rendered html to look something like this: `<form editable-form action="" class"" method="" etc...></form>` (I am working with Angularjs-xeditable)

Here is the link for an example of what I am looking to accomplish in ASP.NET [Angular-xeditable](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-form)

Comment: Any reason why this is being marked down? Please let me know if you need more details. Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can use an anonymous type, because you'd need a property called 'editable-form', which is illegal.  Does my answer work?

Comment: I have yet to find a way nor have I been able to deduce whether it is possible via the html helper to render an anonymous attribute. All indications so far shows that this is not doable

Answer (score 0):

There's often an extension method that will take a dictionary of html attributes.  I think you can use this one:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470539(v=vs.118).aspx

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", FormMethod.Post, new Dictionary<string,object>{ {"editable-form",""} }))
{
}
```

If this one isn't what you need, check out the rest of the list for another one that allows you to specify attributes, or you'll have to write your own: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions(v=vs.118).aspx.

Comment: Yes, I looked into those but does not accomplish the task.